# Meaning of adding 1 on socket file descriptor in select function when using linux socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, select

What is the meaning of adding 1 on socket file descriptor when using in select function?

I create socket file descriptor like below,

```
int sock_file_descriptor;
sock_file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

and use it in select function like below,

```
result = select(sock_file_descriptor+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

What is the meaning of +1 in select function?
It even does not work when I remove the calculation adding the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation [reads](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html): `nfds`: *This argument should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1. The indicated file descriptors in each set are checked, up to this limit (but see BUGS).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM! The first parameter of `select` is the number of file descriptors to considere:

> The nfds argument specifies the range of descriptors to be tested. The first nfds descriptors shall be checked in each set; that is, the descriptors from zero through nfds-1 in the descriptor sets shall be examined.

Here is an example of use:

```
// create socket
int sock_file_descriptor;
sock_file_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

// initialize the read fd_set
fd_set read;
FD_ZERO(&read);
FD_SET(sock_file_descriptor, &read);

// ok we can select
result = select(sock_file_descriptor+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, 0);
```